# pip path does not match module search path

Tags: python, pip, python-import

pip is installing to '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', but that path is not in `sys.path`.  How do I permanently tell python to load packages from here?  For a temporary solution, I've tried `sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')` but that has no effect.

edit: my error message

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/wy/nplx__q112xcnspm7454nk_h0000gn/T/pip_build_<user>/numpy-stl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/wy/nplx__q112xcnspm7454nk_h0000gn/T/pip-59wzi0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wy/nplx__q112xcnspm7454nk_h0000gn/T/pip_build_<user>/numpy-stl
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/<user>/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: There's not just one `pip` binary. You have to find and call `pip` that belongs to your interpreter. See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation

Comment: @cel when I try that I get a compilation error from pip so I'm attempting to circumvent that buy moving the successfully compiled module

Comment: I would recommend understanding and solving the compilation error instead. Copying compiled python modules around is very error prone. There's simply too much that can go wrong.

Comment: just reinstall pip using the python interpreter you want to use and pip will then install using the path for that interpreter,  why did you install another version of python?