# Installed Tweepy but unable to import into iPython Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I installed Tweepy 3.5.0 from the command line using both:

```
easy install tweepy
```

And later:

```
pip install tweepy
```

After uninstalled.

And it successfully installed in `C:\python27\lib\site-packages`.

---

I'm using Python 2.7.1 in iPython Notebook. When I run:

```
import python
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named tweepy
```

Is Tweepy installed in the wrong path?

Comment: Don't you want to import tweepy (not import python)? And, you mention ipython notebook specifically. Are you getting different results in ipython notebook compared to at the command line?

Comment: Here, I sketch the problem you see: It's the same for `python` and `ipython` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation
The key is to find out to which interpreter `ipython` belongs and install `tweepy` exactly to that interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pip not installed properly, therefore please follow up the below steps and share the feedback.

```
C:\>pip install tweepy
```

The first command is enough provided that pip has been added to the Path environment variable of your system. To check it out, do this:

```
    Open Command Prompt (DOS prompt).
    Type python and press enter.
    Once python prompt (>>>) appears, type import pip and press enter.
```

If you see an error, then pip has not been added to the environment variable Path. If there's no error whatsoever, then pip is installed properly.

In that case, re-install Python once and try again. I am using Python 3.5 and tweepy works fine for me. I see that you are using Python 2.7.1 version. I hope Python has been properly installed. If you want, try uninstalling Python and then re-installing it properly just to make sure. I will also suggest you to try using Python 3.x version once to see if you get the same error.