# How to install packages in different version of python?

Tags: python, pip, versions

I have a MacBook Pro that came pre-installed with `python2.7`. I later installed `python3` and `ipython` notebook. I installed `pip` too to install packages, and am able to install packages and run program from `python3`. However, for another project I need to run code in `python2.7`, and I am not sure how to install it in `python2.7` folder.

I tried using pip for installing packages to 2.7, but it kept giving error saying package already exists. When I check for version of python using `--version`, I see 2 pythons installed. However, when I check for `pip` and `pip3`, both seem to be in th same folder.

Any tips on how to install packages in `python2.7`, without making any changes to 3.3? I am using python3 and `ipython` notebooks for another project.

```
viveks-mbp:~ vivekyadav$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip
viveks-mbp:~ vivekyadav$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip3

viveks-mbp:~ vivekyadav$ which python
/usr/bin/python
viveks-mbp:~ vivekyadav$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions), [how to pip install to specific version of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-pip-install-to-specific-version-of-python)

Comment: if you have the package downloaded... `python setup.py install --home="Path/to/python2.7/install"` should just install it to 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `virtualenv` to create a kind of sandbox.

```
$ virtualenv <work-directory>
$ source <work-directory>/bin/activate
```

The last command initiate your virtual environment, totally isolated from the system. So every `pip` command will install the package inside this directory.

But you have to run your application inside the virtual environment too.