# getting error for importing numpy at Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed numpy-1.11.0b3 by, pip install "numpy-1.11.0b3+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl". The installation became successful.

But, when I write "import numpy" at the Python Shell (3.5.1), I am getting the error as - ImportError: No module named 'numpy'.

Can anyone suggest me regarding this ?

Regards, Arpan Ghose

Comment: Do you have several Python installations? It is possible that numpy was installed into one location and you run Python which looks for it in another location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation

Comment: You may have more than one version of python. Type python --version at the command line to see what it says. If its not 3.5 then you found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you have have installed pip for some lower version of python. To check it first look for your default python version by:

> $python

Now check for your linked version of python with pip

> $pip --version

Now see if the two python versions match.
If they don't match then, you need to upgrade you pip :

> $pip install -U pip

Now install numpy for this:

> sudo pip install numpy

Hope this helps !