# Python can't import requests, numpy

Tags: numpy, import, python-3.5

I downloaded a Python 3.5 application which needs to import requests, overpy, numpy and tk. So, when I try to import, say, requests, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named 'requests'

I have searched the internet for answers and the best I could find is in this link [getting error for importing numpy at Python 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577179/getting-error-for-importing-numpy-at-python-3-5-1) . I do have other versions installed, 2.7 is installed by default, however knowing where the problem is doesn't offer a solution.

If it is relevant to configuration issues, I have a Mac with El Capitan.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577179/getting-error-for-importing-numpy-at-python-3-5-1?noredirect=1&lq=1 Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pip installed? It's likely that you don't have the package readily available. You will need to download pip for your operating system (if you haven't already), then run

```
pip install requests
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/

If you have pip installed and think you have requests installed as well, then run

```
pip freeze
```

It's most likely not an issue with your python versions, though you will want to be sure when you install pip that it is installed in the correct location.

Comment: I probably don't have pip: the terminal says -bash pip: command not found. How do I install pip and where should it go?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to need it.  :/. That or you will need to clone a LOT of git repositories.

Comment: Right; I need pip but I don't know how to install. Apparently it should have come bundled with python 3.5 but I can't find it.

Comment: No problem! That should solve your requests issue. Also, you'll have to do the same for numpy. Pip is my goto first step for import errors. Good luck!