# import boto3 error on Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, aws-sdk, boto3

I'm trying to install boto3 on my mac (high sierra 10.13.3) and tried to follow : https://github.com/boto/boto3. I had already installed python 3 using homebrew before, but when I tried to see pip --version, I get error.
So, I did

1) modify `.bash_profile` to add

```
alias pip=pip3
```

2) verify

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

3)

```
$ pip install boto3
Collecting boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.5.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 474kB/s
Collecting botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50 (from boto3)
  Downloading botocore-1.8.50-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.1MB 376kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
Installing collected packages: botocore, boto3
  Found existing installation: botocore 1.8.20
    Uninstalling botocore-1.8.20:
      Successfully uninstalled botocore-1.8.20
Successfully installed boto3-1.5.36 botocore-1.8.50
```

4) just to make sure this was fine, I ran

```
$ pip3 install boto3
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Users/ond983/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in /Users/ond983/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /Users/ond983/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /Users/ond983/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/ond983/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.50->boto3)
```

5) but, now when I ran import boto3 in Idle, I get error

```
import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

I even tried to change path in `.bash_profile`, but it did not work.
Thoughts?

Comment: you are using `python` or `python3` to run the script ?

Comment: python3; but I added an alias in my bash profile alias python=python3

Comment: alias part is creating the confusion first check both pip and python using `--version` to know which one is runing .

Comment: $ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6) 
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation

Comment: Try installing bot03 using this way 

`python3 -m pip3 install boto3`

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to just copy all of packages with "bolo" in the name from the Python 3.7 folder to the Python 2.7 folder:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ sudo cp -R boto* /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/.
```

Answer (score 1):

For those seeing this in 2023, check [ImportError after successful pip installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation), as noted by @[Ankur Jyoti Phukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5687769/ankur-jyoti-phukan).
For example, if you use also brew for package management, both the python3 and  boto3 should be installed with boto3. When python3 already installed, for boto3 either:

```
python3 -m pip install boto3
```

or:

```
brew install python-boto3
```