# No module named matplotlib, even though it was successfully installed via pip?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip, cygwin

I'm using `cygwin` in Windows to install `matplotlib`, via `pip` command. Command I used:

`pip install matplotlib`

Message was: "matplotlib successfully installed". I proceeded to run the script, but got the error:

> ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

I then found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32680082/6032016), saying I am supposed to use `python -m pip install matplotlib` instead of the previous command.

However, after entering that command, following error shows:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

How come do I get this error? `pip` does exist in my machine. How can I successfully access/install the `matplotlib` module?

Comment: I restorted to PyCharm for now. The IDE doesn't have these issues, and it's easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Python 3 you have (generally for 3.4 and above), you may want to try the script `pip3 install matplotlib`. `pip3` is the Python 3 version of pip and it installs the Python 3 version of `matplotlib` if it is available.

The problem may also be in your script. Try importing the entire `matplotlib` library into your program and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: if I use `pip3` command, the message is same as with pip: "Requirement already satisfied". Also the problem is not in the script, because not even the entire library can be loaded