# Successfully installed package (Bcrypt) but still gives error

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I successfully installed Bcrypt but it still gives error (Seems like nothing happened):

```
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
```

The issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*path*", line 9, in <module>
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bcrypt'
```

Comment: Do not post Images, copy and paste the code and the issue.

Comment: @VineethSai sorry for inconvenience. done.

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: How did you install Bcrypt

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation/32680082#32680082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image it looks like you're using Pycharm, Make sure you install `flask_bcrypt` specific to that virtual environment. Bring up the terminal and `pip install flask-bcrypt`

And Change the import statement to

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
```

-From the [docs](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)