# Why can't I import pyvista package in python after installing it

Tags: python, pip, pyvista

I want to use pyvista package in Spyder. I installed pyvista using pip and got the following confirmation:

[image]

but when I try to import it in python (Spyder or Jupyter notebook) I get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvista
```

I have tried uninstalling pyvista and reinstalling but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add your importing code, and *exactly* what you ran to call pip.  You probably have multiple python installations and are installing for the wrong version.

Comment: (Also, what OS are you on?)

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation/32680082#32680082

Comment: I am on windows. the statements I used to install pyvista are as follows:
"
pip uninstall pyvista" and then 
pip install pyvista "

Once that was done I imported using the statement:"import pyvista as pv"