# Cannot Import Python Module that is Installed (for a Luigi Task)

Tags: python, luigi

I've taken a look at all forums on SO regarding this error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize) but I cannot seem to resolve my issue.

I'm trying to import the `us` module but I kept getting the same import error when running a Luigi task: `ImportError: No module named us`

I've tried to force install it with `pip install us —ignore-installed` as well as uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Below is the output of `pip show us`

```
 pip show us
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: us
Version: 0.9.1
Summary: US state meta information and other fun stuff
Home-page: https://github.com/unitedstates/python-us
Author: Jeremy Carbaugh
Author-email: jcarbaugh@sunlightfoundation.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: jellyfish
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: So the us module works when used without luigi, but it fails (import error) when used inside of luigi?  Or is the us module not being found at all?

Comment: Yes it is the former. When I try importing `us` inside a standalone python shell, it'll work. But for some reason luigi doesn't seem to recognize the module when importing.

Comment: How are you importing it when using luigi? How are you running your luigi pipeline?

Comment: it would be nice to see your task and how you are running it