# python module not found even after installation

Tags: python-3.x

```
(venv) [root@z1 myproject]# ./tst.py

3.5.1 (default, Jul 13 2016, 08:50:23)

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./tst.py", line 5, in <module>

    from tabulate import tabulate

ImportError: No module named 'tabulate'

(venv) [root@z1 myproject]#


(venv) [root@z1 myproject]# python

Python 3.5.1 (default, Jul 13 2016, 08:50:23)

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

.>>> from tabulate import tabulate

.>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import a python module that is definitely installed (mechanize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I resolved it. I've installed that module in virtual environment while script referred to use python installed under /usr/local/bin/python3.5. Issue resolved when i changed it to /usr/bin/env python