# Python Module not found error even when the module is installed

Tags: python, macos, python-module

When I try to import the Image module, it fails to find the module.

```
nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Image
>>>
```

Pip list shows that it is installed.

```
nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
appnope (0.1.0)
bleach (1.5.0)
cycler (0.9.0)
dask (0.13.0)
decorator (4.0.11)
distribute (0.7.3)
Django (1.10.5)
email (6.0.0a1)
entrypoints (0.2.2)
Flask (0.10.1)
html5lib (0.9999999)
image (1.5.5)
```

I'm using Mac's default python version.

```
nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The PYTHONPATH variable seems to be empty, but when I try to import other already installed packages it does not show the "no module found" error.

```
nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I have also tried everything stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize), but it didn't work for me.

**Update**

As Suggested that modules are case sensitive, I tried the following, it but didn't work either.

```
nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named image
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `import image` instead of `import Image`

module names are case-sensitive

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

`nn-MacBook-Pro-3:~ nn$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named image
`