# StandPOSTagger in Python "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp, text-mining

I recently try to learn nltk package through http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-v-using-stanford-text-analysis-tools-in-python.
But I faced a question about performing JAVA code in Python:

```
import os
java_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\\bin\java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
os.environ['JAVAHOME']
```

It turned out:

```
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121\\bin\\java.exe'
```

Then I run nltk code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
english_postagger=StanfordPOSTagger('models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger','stanford-postagger.jar')
english_postagger.tag('hi')
```

However:

```
`Error: Could not find or load main class`edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger
```

I reviewed the documents in 'stanford-postagger.jar', the MaxentTagger file was there:
[path to Maxent Tagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAmHy.jpg)

May I know how I could set right class path? or other way to solve this problem.
P.S. : I don't have experience in Java, but Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you don't have access to the jars, so this is a CLASSPATH issue.  I'm not positive this will work with `nltk`, but I've seen previous answers where setting `os.environ["CLASSPATH"]= "/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31"` solves this.

You can download Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0 from here:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

If you want to use our tools in Python, I would recommend using the Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0 server and making small server requests (or using the `stanza` library).

If you use `nltk` what I believe happens is Python just calls our Java code with `subprocess` and this can actually be very inefficient since distinct calls reload all of the models.

Here is a previous answer I gave which describes this more thoroughly:

[cannot use pycorenlp for python3.5 through terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896027/cannot-use-pycorenlp-for-python3-5-through-terminal/42915635#42915635)

Comment: Thanks you so much for help!  I didn't have experience in JAVA, so it looks like I need to learn about it. I would try stanza to understand the problem definitely.

Comment: More info on the server: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html