# Trying to parse tree using Stanford Dependency

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

Hi I am trying to get the tokens int he format:

> Token(index=1, form='some', cpos='DT', pos='DT', head=3, deprel='det')
>   Token(index=2, form='blue', cpos='JJ', pos='JJ', head=3, deprel='amod')
>   Token(index=3, form='moose', cpos='NN', pos='NN', head=0, deprel='root')

When passed "some blue moose". When i run below code

```
>>> import StanfordDependencies
>>> sd = StanfordDependencies.get_instance(backend='subprocess')
>>> sent = sd.convert_tree('(S1 (NP (DT some) (JJ blue) (NN moose)))')
```

for convert_tree(), i am getting the 
error.

> File "D:\ABC\anaconda\lib\site-packages\StanfordDependencies\SubprocessBackend.py", line 127, in _raise_on_bad_exit_or_output
>       raise ValueError("Bad exit code from Stanford CoreNLP")
>   ValueError: Bad exit code from Stanford CoreNLP

Can someone help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should look over this response to how to you Stanford CoreNLP with Python:

[cannot use pycorenlp for python3.5 through terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896027/cannot-use-pycorenlp-for-python3-5-through-terminal/42915635#42915635)

It shows how to start a StanfordCoreNLP server and make requests via Python.  If you include the `depparse` annotator in your list of annotators you can get back dependency parses.