# Remove sudo to run python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, permissions, authorization, sudo

Every time that I need to run my python program with:

```
python my_program.py
```

I get some error saying that some import was not found.

Some error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graphic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Than I run:

```
sudo python my_program.py
```

And every thing works just fine. How do I remove the sudo command to run my python codes?

Comment: Seems that you install Python under sudo, so the later command without sudo cannot access the folder with root permissions. Try to reinstall python, remember don't always use sudo to install things, you may ruin the permission management.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import a python module that is definitely installed (mechanize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize)

Answer (score 2):

`ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'` happens when your Python doesn't find the module. `sudo` changes the **enviornment** variables; That's why.

To fix this, locate where `matplotlib` is installed in your computer, and verify the folder is part of your `sys.path`.

```
import sys
sys.path
['C:\\Python27\\tests', ..., ...]
```

Then you've two options: insert that path from your script, i.e adding a line such `import sys; sys.path.append(<folder>)` or configure `PYTHONPATH` env variable under your user appending the folder to the path.

`PYTHONPATH` env variable gets loaded to `sys.path` on startup.

Comment: I did not understand the second option, how can I config the PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution to me is a general workflow for all projects: use virtualenviroment][1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv myenv
source mynenv/bin/activate
```

Then you should install your libraries again with pip and they will be installed in your virtualenviroment, isolated from everything else.