# No module named 'tqdm'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pixel, recurrent-neural-network, tqdm

I am running the following pixel recurrent neural network (RNN) code using Python 3.6

```
import os
import logging

import numpy as np
from tqdm import trange
import tensorflow as tf

from utils import *
from network import Network
from statistic import Statistic
```

However, there was an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you actually installed this module? If so how did you do it?

Comment: Yes, I have installed using pip install tqdm

Comment: can you run command and check that its installed or not  using pip list or pip show tqdm

Comment: if you are using Python3 shouldnt it be `pip3 ...`?

Comment: if module is properly installed then you can refer this link to debug more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize

Comment: Same case with pip install -e git+https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm.git@master#egg=tqdm

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to install tqdm module, you can do it by using python pip.

```
pip install tqdm
```

for more info [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#latest-pypi-stable-release)

Comment: For Anaconda use: `conda install -c conda-forge tqdm`, also for pip3 use: `pip3 install tqdm`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I have tried "pip install tdqm" and "pip3 install tdqm". But even though the console confirms that it has been installed, python claims it is not. I also tried running this code block `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'tdqm'])` in python, and the console agrees that tdqm has been installed, but when I try to import it, it cannot find tdqm. I have **not** installed any pip installs before on this PC, though I have done it on another PC that also has Windows 10, where I downloaded python from the same place on both PC. What is the problem?

Answer (score 22):

For Python 3 as you specified, you use the `pip3` command, like so...

```
pip3 install tqdm
```

For Python 2, you use `pip` command, like so...

```
pip install tqdm
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

or you can use `conda install -c conda-forge tqdm` Sometimes help

Answer (score 4):

In Anaconda this worked for me:

```
sudo <anaconda path>/bin/python3.6 -m pip install tqdm
```

(after your working env is activated)

On my linux machine I substituted `<anaconda path>` with:

```
anaconda3
```

Ubuntu machines:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3.5 -m pip install tqdm
```

Comment: **Note:** If you're using Conda then you should install tqdm (and all modules when possible) with Conda itself, not pip.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed it, type :

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

at the beggining of your code

Answer (score 2):

In Anaconda, steps to install the package.

1. Navigate to ‘Environments” and Search for your package.
2. That package will be displayed and click on Apply.

Now the package is installed and it can be used right away.

Please share your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Albeit I'm using a virtual environment, what solved my problem was executing

```
sudo apt install python3-tqdm
```

Weirdly enough my issue was solved by installing tqdm globally in my system.

Answer (score -1):

*the simpler approach worked for me*

Manual Solution for Dependency Issues:

If you encounter dependency problems within your Python virtual environment, you can address them manually with the following steps:

Open a Command Prompt (cmd):

Launch the Windows Command Prompt.
Navigate to the Scripts Directory:

Use the cd command to navigate to the Scripts directory within your virtual environment. Replace YOURPATH with the actual path to your virtual environment:
cd YOURPATH\venv\Scripts
Activate the Virtual Environment:

Run the activate.bat script to activate the virtual environment:
activate.bat
Upgrade Packages:

To upgrade specific packages, use python -m pip install --upgrade . Replace  with the name of the package you want to upgrade. For example, to upgrade the tqdm package:
python -m pip install --upgrade tqdm
You can apply this command for any package you suspect is corrupted or needs an upgrade.

Please note that these steps involve manual package management within a virtual environment. If you are unfamiliar with these commands, consider seeking assistance from someone with experience to avoid unintended consequences.

Disclaimer:
The effectiveness of these manual steps may vary depending on the specific issue. It’s important to exercise caution, especially if you’re not familiar with the commands involved.

If you prefer a simpler approach, you can also try the following:

Remove Corrupted Extensions:

Delete any corrupted extensions within the “extensions” folder in your virtual environment.
Delete the Virtual Environment:

As a last resort, delete the entire virtual environment folder (e.g., “venv”).
Relaunch:

After making these changes, relaunch your project. This may help resolve dependency issues.
Always remember to back up important data before making any significant changes to your environment.