# Error when trying to import 'time'

Tags: python, python-3.x

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'time.sleep'; 'time' is not a package

This is the error I get when I type `import time.sleep as sleep` using 3.7.0a IDLE. Not sure about the `as sleep` part, but the `import time.sleep` seems to be broken or something like that. I tried the same thing with `import time` as well, got the same result. Could someone please explain?

> Edit:
>   I was told that I should try 'import time' first and then 'time.sleep', but as >I said before:
>
> > ```
> >     I tried the same thing with 'import time' as well...
> > ```
> >
> > that does not work either. And another suggestion was that maybe I had >another file named time.py, and that it confused the programme. But as far as I >know (from a full search through my computer), I do not have another time.py >file that might be the cause. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Simply `import time` should work fine.

Comment: As I said, it does the same when I use 'import time' it just says 'time' is not a package

Comment: Then there must be a name collision. Make sure there are no files called `time.py` in your working directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import a python module that is definitely installed (mechanize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following and it will work:

```
from time import sleep
```

The reason your import did not work is because `time.sleep` is not a module. `sleep` is a method (function). If you use `import time` and then `time.sleep()` it will work as well.

Comment: If `time` is not importable (probably because there is a file name which shadows the standard module, as hinted in other comments) no variation like this is going to work, either.

Comment: If you try `import time as s` you will get the same error OP asked, saying that time is not a package. I assumed OP didn't try to do import time... he later said he tried to import time, but I had already answered this.

Answer (score 0):

sleep is a method of time module, so first you need to import the module and then you can use methods of it, In your case:

```
>>> import time 
>>> time.sleep
```

or

`>>> from time import sleep`

should work, But as you said `import time` is also not working, So you need to make sure that there's no time.py file present in your directory (from where you're invoking the python shell)