# Visual Studio Code does not see wget

Tags: python, wget

I have Python 2.7 installed on my machine. I use it in Visual Studio Code (VSC) (MacOS distribution) without issue, but I'm having difficulty getting Visual Studio Code to "see" `wget`.

In my VSC, I added the following import statement to `myProject.py`:

```
import wget
```

The linter says this:

> E0401:Unable to import 'wget'

I verified I have `wget` installed via the following command:

```
which wget
```

...which returns...

```
/usr/local/bin/wget
```

I attempted to reinstall it with `brew install wget`, but it says it's installed already. So I tried `sudo -H pip install wget`, which I think installed successfully.

> Collecting wget   Downloading wget-3.2.zip Building wheels for
>   collected packages: wget   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for wget ...
>   done   Stored in directory:
>   /var/root/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/6d/98/29/61ccc41148f871009126c2e844e26f73eeb25e12cca92228a5
>   Successfully built wget Installing collected packages: wget
>   Successfully installed wget-3.2

I closed VSC and reopened it. I continue to get this error in the linter:

> E0401:Unable to import 'wget'

I recently installed and uninstalled `anaconda`, which I'm pretty sure is the source of my misery. I don't regularly work with Python, but I find myself working on a project where it's pretty handy. I'm out of ideas re: how to resolve this issue. I welcome your suggestions and I thank you for reading.

**Update:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14295680/4475605) describes the issue I've encountered. I've tried the solutions suggested and none of them seem to rid me of the linter error.

Updating my `.bash_profile` does not to appear to have any effect, either:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: The `wget` that you have is a _program_, not a Python module. You cannot import it. You can execute it from Python using `system` or some other function.

Comment: @DyZ Yes, I'm aware of that. The issue is that I have `wget` installed, but my compiler doesn't see it and generates an error that it's unable to import it.

Comment: What do you get with `python -c "import wget"`? That's the only way to know for sure if it's installed properly. Sorry that above commenters failed to understand the question, but whether `which wget` succeeds is unrelated to if the python module is installed.

Comment: I think I had issue like this before, `wget` needs to be in your System's path. In my case, I am using windows, so I needed to include the following in my `PATH environment variable`: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;

Comment: @ElliottBeach Nothing happens when I type `python -c "import wget"` in terminal. If I type just `python`, I get `Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)` and I can get out of it with `quit()`.

Comment: Can you do a `sudo python -c "import wget"`, i think the python you are are using in terminal and VS code are different

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @FelippeDaMottaRaposo No. I'm just running code within Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue with my Python installation. I'm not sure what it was or why, as the other packages I had installed worked fine (`matplotlib`, etc.).

Here's how I resolved it:

I uninstalled `python` via home-brew, as follows:

`brew uninstall python`

Then, I reinstalled `python` via `brew` as follows:

`brew install python`

I opened my `.bash_profile` with the following command in Terminal:

`open .bash_profile`

I commented out prior the path and added this one (don't nuke a path unless you're sure you don't need it):

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

Then, I followed the brew prompts to finish the install. Upon completion, I installed `wget` via `pip2` as follows:

```
pip2 install wget
```

After that, I opened up Visual Studio Code, typed `import wget` and it worked.

Comment: I think the important part is installing the `wget` **python module** with `pip`, rather than just installing the wget package with `brew`. I don't think there was necessarily anything wrong with the python installation.

Comment: @ohlec I'm not sure of the precise cause of the issue I encountered, but I had installed and removed `anaconda` which seems to have fouled up some programs that had previously worked. I got it to a workable state with the exception of `wget` and a couple of others (now resolved). Next time I encounter flakiness like that, I'll probably reinstall python as a first step, not a last.