# How to import pandas for python3?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have a python script that uses pandas library. But when I try to install pandas using:

```
pip install pandas
```

It says:

```
Installing collected packages: pytz, six, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.5 pandas-0.23.3 python-dateutil-2.7.3 pytz-2018.5 six-1.11.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

When I try to run my script again, it tells again that no module named pandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

After using the suggestion, I tried again pip install pandas but i get an error

`Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module> 
     from pip import main 
ImportError: cannot import name main`

Comment: First use `'pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Read this, [Cannot import a python module that is definitely installed (mechanize)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14295680).

Comment: After using your suggestion, I tried again `pip install pandas` but i get an error `      Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
      from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main`

Comment: The module is successfully installed. If you are using Jupyter try to close and open again in a new notebook.

Comment: I think the problem is `python-dateutil-2.7.3`

Comment: You should upgrade your pip.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a workaround while someone points out a definitive solution for your [dependency hell](https://www.certdepot.net/python-dependency-hell/): use a virtual environment.

Using miniconda, [download your package](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), install it and:

```
conda create -n py37 anaconda python=3.7
source activate py37
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the command line, make sure you execute the script using `python3` (instead of `python`), e.g.

```sh
python3 filename.py
```