# Cannot import module after installed by pip

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I have already installed my wanted module from pip by using pip install but when i open up a program in idle and put import menu it says module not found what did i do wrong, im using python 3.7 and have the latest version of pip.

Comment: have you created an environment for this setup? which is the pip version?

Comment: Possibly, pip and python are different versions. Try reinstalling with `python -m pip install <whatever>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python looks for its modules and packages in `$PYTHONPATH`. You'll need to figure out if the `__init__.py` module of the package you'd like to use is in python's path. To find out whether it is in python's path, run:

```
    import sys
    print(sys.path)
```

within python.

To add the path to your module, run:

`sys.path.append("/path/to/your/package_or_module")`

and you should be set.

Comment: It works when I run the code with "python main.py" in the console, but the module name is still highlighted as "Not found" by VS Code, and the debugger marks it as an error. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but in my case the package is created by myself. So this answer applyes to the custom packages. See Why customer python package can not be imported? for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is meeting a similar problem to mine.
Pay attention to the case of the package. In my case, the package is called 'shapely'. And I installed it through

```
pip install Shapely
```

But you have to import as

```
import shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: figure out what paths are included in current notebook session

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Step 2: figure out where your package is installed

```
!pip show YOUR_PACKAGE
```

Make your the path in Step 2 is included in Step 1 list.
If not, try:

```
!pip install --target=d:\some\path\thats\in\step1\list YOUR_PACKAGE
```