# no module name keyboard in raspberry pi zero python version 3.7.3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-zero

could not use module keyboard, i have check using `python3 -m pip list` to check the pip packages that i have installed and i saw that i have installed `keyboard 0.13.5` , however after i execute this code

```
import keyboard

shortcut = 'alt+x'
good = 'shift+a'
def on_triggered():
    print('hi')

keyboard.add_hotkey(shortcut,on_triggered)
keyboard.add_hotkey(good,on_triggered)

keyboard.wait('esc')
```

i still get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'`

even if i have install the module with this code `python3 -m pip install keyboard` and this code `pip3 install keyboard`. please help me i am using raspberry pi zero with python version 3.7.3

btw this work on window 10 but it does not work on raspberry pi zero.

i have check other question and follow their instruction by installing with python3 -m pip install, but nothing changed.

this is what it said after i install

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.13.5)
```

Comment: Ok it could be a version problem. If you have multiple versions of python installed, you would have to install keyboard for the one you are using

Comment: this was the feedback from the terminal 
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.13.5)

Comment: Ok so when you run the program, what python version does it say it's using?

Comment: are you talking abou the py script? i execute the code with sudo python3 script.py

Comment: What is the output of running `sudo python3 --version`?

Comment: python 3.7.3 is the output

Comment: So it seems that keyboard is installed for your python version correctly...I can't think of what's wrong. If you run `sudo python3`, then `import keyboard` in the python shell, does it still say module not found?

Comment: yes it still say the same thing, it work fine in window but once i try it on raspberry pi i get the error

Comment: Your filename with the code is not called keyboard.py by any chance is it? Naming the file the same as the import often causes problems

Comment: no the py name is test.py

Comment: Do any of these solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: Which answer says "no such file or directory"?

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` this one and `sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: You have version 3.7 so you would have to change the command accordingly

Comment: Also, I looked at the docs of keyboard and you can download the repo from GitHub and reference it directly

Comment: Without having to install anything