# already install flask-sqlalchemy in virtual environment but unresolved import error is showing in flask app

Tags: flask

from flask-sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy showing unresolved import error. But i already install flask sqlalchemy in cmd using pip install flask-sqlalchemy command.In python shell in command line sqlalchemy is importing normally there is no problem but in flask app its showing import error

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template

    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'


     all_post=[
     {
    'title':'post1',
    'content':'content of post1',
    'author':'dipanjan'
     },
     {
    'title':'post2',
    'content':'content of post2'
     }
     ]

     @app.route('/posts')
     def posts():
     return render_template('posts.html', posts=all_post)

     @app.route('/')
     def home():
       return render_template('index.html')

     if __name__ =="__main__":   
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: are you sure you've installed with pip3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed

Comment: sometimes this happen when you have python2 with pip and python3 with pip3 and you misuse them accidentally

Comment: i upgrade pip using  "pip install --upgrade pip" this command But showing me this environment error please help me to solve this

Comment: Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\pip-uninstall-tao9rdef\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

İf you use venv and you cant see your packages, go ypur venv path and run this code below:

```
pip freeze
```

and check your package you want