# ImportError when using pip install

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I tried installing 'pandas' and 'xlrd' using pip install but I get this error from python when I try and use the modules: **ImportError: No module named xlrd**. Same error when I use pandas. I have tried various methods from the internet to solve this issue including:

- changing package permissions
- using sudo pip install
- adding PYTHONPATH export in the bash_profile file.
- using pip3 because I have python 3

I even tried this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602260, but in my case I already had the package location(which I got using pip show xlrd) inside the sys.path list.

None of the above approaches have worked for me.

Edit: I use VSCode as my IDE and I run my files through the inbuilt terminal.

Comment: Sounds like you have more than one version of python installed on your system.  How, exactly, do you run the python code?  Do you type `python script.py` on the command prompt, or do you use an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: `python3 -m pip install xlrd pandas`. Don't bother with `sudo` if it's not necessary: Python/pip will use a user installation instead. If your Python command is different, change it accordingly.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your reply! It made me realise that the problem is with the IDE  and not pip as it works when I use the terminal to run. Any answers on why VScode is behaving that way?

Comment: Probably because VSCode is set up with the incorrect Python executable.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks a lot it works after changing the settings to the correct path

Comment: Run each of these commands to see where your Python and Pip installs are located: 'which python', 'which python3', 'which pip', 'which pip3'. Then try to run the python version with the full path from VSCode.