# 'scipy' seems to be installed but can not be imported

Tags: pip, scipy, homebrew

Here is the error I am receiving when running python 3.10.1 in my terminal.

```
import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I used

```
pip3 install scipy
```

and everything seemed to work. If I run it again I receive this

```
pip3 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.25.0,>=1.17.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.22.3)
```

I also tried

```
brew install scipy
```

and that too seemed to work and if I run it again I get this message

```
brew install scipy
Warning: scipy 1.8.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.8.0, run:
brew reinstall scipy
```

Why wont python3 import scipy?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in terminal and now everything works

```
python3 -m pip install scipy
```

I am still unsure what the original issue was however it may be related to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed).