# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_translator'" on a module tha is installed

Tags: python

I'm getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\svp12\PycharmProjects\practiques\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_translator'
```

But the module is installed

[image]

Comment: have you tried running it from terminal, as shown in the docs: https://deep-translator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#quick-start like this: `deep-translator translate -src "en" -tgt "de" -txt "some text to translate"` ?

Comment: @35308 gives me this error:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>deep-translator translate -src "en" -tgt "de" -txt "tests.txt"
usage: dt --help
deep-translator: error: unrecognized arguments: translate -tgt de


But I need to do it from python becouse I have to translate lots of documents

Comment: it seems like it can run through terminal but not through python, do you use a virtual environment for python (conda...) if not here are some potential fixes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed
it could be a python path problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not installed the package into the project's virtual environment. Try activating the project's venv as below and install the package:

```
{project_dir}/venv/Scripts/activate
pip install deep_translator
```