# Cannot import name 'fbchat' (ImportError)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install the fbchat module for Python on Ubuntu 22.04. The install seems to have been succesful, but whenever i try to launch a script with the module in it, i get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'fbchat' from 'fbchat' (/home/atlas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fbchat/**init**.py)

Before i installed, i updated my system, i am using Python v. 3.10.6 and pip v. 22.0.2.
I have tried both the pip install, pip3 install, git-cloning and tarball installation methods, but the error keeps repeating. I am unable to find others with the same error, so i hope someone can provide me some clarity as to why this happens, and hopefully a fix.

Comment: you might want to take a look of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377297/1781986

Comment: How are you importing it? Please provide the import statement used in the script.

Comment: Ive tried both "import fbchat" and "from fbchat import fbchat", the result is the same.

Comment: how do you install fbchat? "sudo pip install" or just "pip install"?

Comment: Tried both, also looked at the thread you posted and used chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages. Problem sadly still persists.

Comment: did you say "sudo chmod 777" or just "chmod 777"? if you just say "chmod 777" it won't work, assuming your directory is only root +rw permission. Plus, it seems the package you import from is not from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages but /home/atlas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fbchat

Comment: Paul Wang, i figured it out thanks to your guidance. Thank you so much!

Comment: As an addendum to this question: does anyone know if the module is still working? I'm getting login errors, and as far as i can read, the module is no longed updated and possibly patched out by Facebook themselves.

Comment: I would recommend you post a new question for your "addendum".

Answer (score 0):

If you install fbchat using

```
sudo pip install fbchat
```

then the package might somehow installed with root rw permission only, other user just cannot rw to it!

you might need to change your package permission to add +rx to user or group, for example, in your case:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /home/atlas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fbchat/
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /home/atlas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
```