# Unable to import (custom) python module

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I have a custom module called my_module. It is structured like this:

```
 <my_module>
    __init__.py
    file_1_with_methods.py
    setup.py
    subdirectory
        __init__.py
        file_2_with_methods.py

    etc.
```

`__init__.py` is empty. setup.py looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='<my_module>'
    , author = '<me>'
    , author_email ='<my_email>'
    , version='1.0.0'
    , description='<descriptiong>'
    , packages = find_packages()
    , install_requires = required
    , include_package_data=True # include non-python files in the install
)
```

I installed it using

```
 pip install /path/to/my/module
```

I know it is installed to the same location as all my other packages because I ran

```
pip list -v
```

and the Location is the same as all the others. I verified that the location is in the python path using

```
 import sys
 sys.path
```

I also verified that I am using the same user (root) for both the install, and when running the import call.

Furthermore I only have one installed version of python.

That covers everything mentioned here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed)

I tried asking chatGPT and it mentioned confirming the name of the package (done), but didn't really have anything else to contribute.

Comment: To haven't actually described the problem