# Problem installing Pytrends on WIndows: Module not found

Tags: python

I have just begun learning Python so I'm not very confident. I have installed Python 3.8.2 and added the location of my installation directory to my PATH in Windows 11. However I cannot get the Pytrends module to work.

I can execute Python commands directly in Command Prompt, and also run scripts in Pycharm.

I'm trying to install Pytrends, following the guide [here](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/). I ran

```
pip install pytrends
```

Which came up with a load of "Requirement already satisfied" reports. I'm not clear on whether it completed installation

```
C:\Users\username>pip install pytrends
Requirement already satisfied: pytrends in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (4.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pytrends) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.25 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pytrends) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pytrends) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.23.2 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25->pytrends) (1.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25->pytrends) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25->pytrends) (2023.3.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25->pytrends) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pytrends) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pytrends) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pytrends) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pytrends) (2023.7.22)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas>=0.25->pytrends) (1.16.0)
```

However, when I run this command from the guide in command line or in my app script:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

I receve the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'
```

I don't really understand this. If I go into my appdata folder, I can see the pytrends folders in there so I think it's installed.

Comment: Try: `pip install --upgrade pytrends`

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `pip --version` aswell as `python --version`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had multiple versions of Python installed. Presumably one was bundled with some other softwar eyears ago that I forgot about. This confuses Python.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [existing question on import errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed).

Presumably, you'd know if you used sudo to install. It could be some other Pip step that needs to be configured. It could be an environment variable.