# How to get Python to recognize installed ost module

Tags: python

This is not the same error shown at [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed) so it is not a duplicate.  The resolution of that error involve the module being installed in the wrong directory for the wrong version of python.  That is not the case here.

I installed the `ost` module with `pip install ost`.

I confirmed that it is installed with `pip list`.

[image]

I try to run a tutorial script that uses ost:

```
import modeller
import ost
# change directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/realt/OneDrive/Documents/Biology Projects/Junk/')
# print content of directory to screen
print('Files before modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n\n')

# perform modelling
routine = hm.routines.Routine_promod3(
    alignment=aln,
    target='ARAF',
    templates=['3NY5'],
    tag='model')
routine.generate_models()

print('Files after modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n')

# remove model
os.remove('model_1.pdb')

# change back to tutorial directory
os.chdir('../..')
```

and I get the error:

```
"ost" is required for this functionality, but could not be imported.
```

How can I get python to recognize and import `ost`.

I have tried restarting python, anaconda and my whole system to no avail.

I have run:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\realt> pip show ost
```

And it returned:

```
Name: ost
Version: 0.1.dev13
Summary: OpenSubtitles interface for Python 3
Home-page: http://www.github.com/rlirey/ost
Author: Ryan L. Irey
Author-email: ireyx001@umn.edu
License: Apache 2.0 License
Location: c:\users\realt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: requests
Required-by:
```

I have also run the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

And it returned:

```
['C:\\Users\\realt\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Biology Projects\\Scripts\\Python Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3', '', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\realt\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

And here is the full traceback of the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 9
6 print('Files before modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n\n')
8 # perform modelling
----> 9 routine = hm.routines.Routine_promod3(
10     alignment=aln,
11     target='ARAF',
12     templates=['3NY5'],
13     tag='model')
14 routine.generate_models()
16 print('Files after modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n')

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\routines.py:924, in Routine_promod3.__init__(self, alignment, target, templates, tag)
    915 def __init__(
    916     self,
    917     alignment: typing.Type["Alignment"],
   (...)
    921 ) -> None:
    922     # check dependencies
    923     dependencies = ["ost", "promod3"]
--> 924     self._check_dependencies(dependencies)
    925     # check number of templates
    926     if len(templates) != 1:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\routines.py:238, in Routine._check_dependencies(dependencies)
    236 for dependency in dependencies:
    237     if not _IMPORTS[dependency]:
--> 238         raise ImportError(
    239             '"{}" is required for this functionality, but could '
    240             "not be imported.".format(dependency)
    241         )

ImportError: "ost" is required for this functionality, but could not be imported.
```

The full code that I am working with is as follows:

```
import os

import homelette as hm

os.chdir('C:/Users/realt/OneDrive/Documents/Biology Projects/Junk/')

# read in the alignment
aln = hm.Alignment('aln_01.fasta')

# print to screen to check alignment
aln.print_clustal(line_wrap=70)

# annotate the alignment
aln.get_sequence('ARAF').annotate(seq_type = 'sequence')
aln.get_sequence('3NY5').annotate(seq_type = 'structure',
                              pdb_code = '3NY5',
                              begin_res = '1',
                              begin_chain = 'A',
                              end_res = '81',
                              end_chain = 'A')

import modeller
import ost
# change directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/realt/OneDrive/Documents/Biology Projects/Junk/')
# print content of directory to screen
print('Files before modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n\n')

# perform modelling
routine = hm.routines.Routine_promod3(
    alignment=aln,
    target='ARAF',
    templates=['3NY5'],
    tag='model')
routine.generate_models()

print('Files after modelling:\n' + ' '.join(os.listdir()) + '\n')

# remove model
os.remove('model_1.pdb')

# change back to tutorial directory
os.chdir('../..')
```

I installed Homelette on a totally different machine and tried to import it.  It gave me numerous warnings of dependencies that could not be imported so I think the problem is with Homelette.  The warnings were:

`

```
"C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:68: UserWarning: Module "altmod" could not be imported.
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:68: UserWarning: Module "modeller" could not be imported.
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:68: UserWarning: Module "ost" could not be imported.
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:68: UserWarning: Module "promod3" could not be imported.
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:68: UserWarning: Module "qmean" could not be imported.
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\jamie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\homelette\__init__.py:75: UserWarning: Please install the missing modules in order to enjoy the full functionality of "homology"
  warnings.warn(msg)"
```

`

Comment: It looks like you may have two different installations of python on your computer. Please edit the question to show the output of this command `pip show ost`, and also the output of this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Also, `"ost" is required for this functionality, but could not be imported` is not a standard python error message.  Where, exactly, did that message come from?

Comment: There's nothing to "restart" in Python.  Are you using an IDE?  Even more, your script does not use either `modeller` or `ost`, but it does need `hm`, which you have not imported.

Comment: @JohnGordon I posted what you asked for to the original question.

Comment: Yeah, the call to `hm.routines.Routine_promod3(...)` should have failed immediately because `hm` is undefined.  Clearly this is not your real code.  It's very hard to help when you don't share the real code.

Comment: @TimRoberts modeller and ost are dependencies of homelette which is hm.  I have imported homelette as hm and it should have installed ost as a dependency but when I got the error I tried installing ost by itself using pip install.

Comment: _I have imported homelette as hm_ Then why is that missing from the code example at the top of the question?

Comment: @JohnGordon it is the real code, I just imported homelette as hm in a previous block of code.  I will post all of my code to the original question but it is extremely messy as I tried to worked with some tutorials by making alterations to get this to work.  Standby please.

Comment: If **YOUR** code is not using `modeller` or `ost`, then YOUR code does not need to import them.  `hm` will import whatever it needs.  If you just type `import ost` into your shell, does that work?

Comment: @TimRoberts 'import ost' does work but the tutorial at https://homelette.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial1_Basics.html is what gives the ost import error.  I just explicitly imported it because of the error.

Comment: The homelette module has its own `import ost` statement, which apparently fails, causing the error message you saw.  But you say `import ost` does work for you, which is very strange.  I don't see why it would fail inside the homelette module, but work in your code.

Comment: I see that you posted your full code at the bottom of the question.  Please also post the full error message that you get from running that code.

Comment: @JohnGordon the full error is shown right above the full code.

Comment: No, that is not the full error.  That error says `routine = hm.routines.Routine_promod3(` is on line 9, which does not match the claimed "full code".

Comment: As a side comment, it seems that our difficulty in tracking down the true error is due to the homelette module's "nice" handling of import errors, which unfortunately only serves to hide the real details of what went wrong.  Shame on them.

Comment: @JohnGordon  I must have copied the wrong block of code the first time.  I have edited the code in the original question.  The 'routine = hm.routines.Routine_promod3(' is actually on line 29 as it is shown because the full code resides in several blocks in my notebook but it is the right code this time and the right error.

Comment: My only guess is that you did something in an earlier cell, perhaps unknowingly, that is causing the error.  Try restarting your notebook and run this posted full code in a **single** cell.

Comment: @JohnGordon I installed Homelette on a totally different machine and tried to import it and it gave many warnings of dependencies that were not installed including ost.  That makes me think that the problem is with Homelette.  I tried to install several of the dependencies and they were not found.