# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics' even after installing it

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror, ultralytics

I have a Python program where the first line is the following:

`from ultralytics import YOLO`

I've already ran `pip install ultralytics` in my terminal, but I always get the following error on the above line:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics'`

I've tried numerous things such as running in a different Python environment, uninstalling and reinstalling again, as well as verifying I'm using a version of Python that runs with ultralytics. Yet, the issue still persists. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed)