# Python cannot import name <class>

Tags: python

I've been wrestling most of the night trying to solve an import error.

This is a common issue, but no previous question quite answers my issue.

I am using PyDev (an Eclipse plugin), and the library Kivy (a Python library)

I have a file structure set up like this:

```
<code>
    __init__.py
    main.py
    engine.py
    main_menu_widget.py
```

"code" is held within the eclipse folder "MyProject" but it's not a package so I didn't include it.

The files look like this:

main.py

```
# main.py
from code.engine import Engine

class MotionApp(App):
    # Ommited
```

engine.py

```
# engine.py
from code.main_menu_widget import MainMenuWidget

class Engine():
    # Ommited
```

main_menu_widget.py

```
# main_menu_widget.py
from code.engine import Engine

class MainMenuWidget(Screen):
    pass
```

The error I recieve, in full detail, is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\MyProject\code\main.py", line 8, in <module>
     from code.engine import Engine
   File "C:\MyProject\code\engine.py", line 6, in <module>
     from code.main_menu_widget import MainMenuWidget
   File "C:\MyProject\code\main_menu_widget.py", line 3, in <module>
     from code.engine import Engine
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? I just renamed my entire folder structure because I screwed up this module structure so bad, but I think i'm close to how it should look....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Answer (score 12):

There seems to be a circular import.
from `engine.py` you are importing `main_menu_widget` while from `main_menu_widget`you are importing `engine`.

That is clearly a circular import which is not allowed by python.

Answer (score 5):

it's in the same folder, use a relative package name (it's a good practice to do so anyway):

```
from .engine import Engine
```

Comment: not code.engine? Wouldnt that make more sense, since it's all inside a root "code" package?

Comment: It's generally a good practice to use relative imports when importing things from your own project.

Comment: Fair enough. I just tried it, no luck, it throws the same error, same line. "cannot import name Engine"

Comment: oh, duh - you have a circular dependency, main_menu_widget.py depends on engine.py and vica verca

Comment: Yep, that's a circular dependency. It's a shitty singleton too. Thanks, I posted a new question for this, but did find a way to bypass. Wish the error message was a tad more descriptive! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216424/python-circular-dependencies-and-singletons

Comment: If you do relative imports in the file where you do ``if __name__ == "__main__":``, you will get this error:
``SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`` In that file, it seems you can only do absolute imports.

Answer (score 1):

Your code directory *is* a package. Ensure that the directory above it, i.e `C:\MyProject` judging from your error messages, is in your PYTHONPATH.

Open the context menu by selecting your project and clicking your mouse's right button, then select *Properties*. Select *PyDev - PYTHONPATH* and from there the *Source folders* tab.
Check that the directory mentioned above is present; if it isn't press *Add source folder*, select it from the dialogue and press *OK*.