# Python, Circular Dependencies, and Singletons

Tags: python, import, singleton, circular-dependency, kivy

I've dug myself into quite a hole here.

I'm working on a Python/Kivy app in PyDev.

The app runs off of many systems (about 10), so I shoved them into an engine to handle everything.

For ease of access, I grab the engine via (the worst) singletons

main.py

```
#main.py
from code import engine

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        engine.GetInstance().Initialize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

engine.py

```
#engine.py
from code import system1
from code import system2

gEngineInstance = None
def GetInstance():
    global gEngineInstance
    if (gEngineInstance == None):
        gEngineInstance = Engine()
    return gEngineInstance

class Engine():
    mSystem1 = None
    mSystem2 = None

    def Initialize(self):
        self.mSystem1 = system1.System1()
        self.mSystem2 = system2.System2()
    # Omitted
```

Unfortunatley, this resulted in some nasty circular dependencies.

Main has to create engine, and know about it, which runs engines imports, which runs the system imports.
Problem: Systems imports then import engine, circular reference.

system1.py

```
#system1.py
from code import engine

class System1():
    def SomeMethod(self):
        engine.GetInstance().mSystem2.DoThings()
```

You get the picture.
I bypassed this for now with this hideous code all over the place:

system1.py

```
#system1.py

class System1():
    def SomeMethod(self):
        from code import engine
        engine.GetInstance().mSystem2.DoThings()
```

This stops the import from happening until that line, which is fine, but it looks wrong, eveyrthing feels like i'm doing things wrong.

I'm tempted to just pass Engine as a reference to every systems constructor, but thats a bit of refactoring, and i'd like to know if there's a more decent way to fix this sort of singleton/circular reference issue for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having a "registration" mechanism, where each `system` module "registers" itself with the `Engine` class using some module-level code:

*engine.py*

```
class Engine():
    @classmethod
    def register(cls, type):
        ...
```

*system1.py*

```
from engine import Engine

class System1():
    ...

Engine.register(System1)
```

That way, the `Engine` doesn't directly have to know what gets plugged into it.

Comment: This is... an interesting idea. Some things about these dynamic languages is hard to work with for me, but sometimes, not having a strict type is a pretty handy tool. I'll give this a shot, thanks!