# cannot import name PyMCObjects when import pymc

Tags: numpy, import, module, pymc, gcc4.9

I have pymc installed, and I am now trying to import it in my code. However,

First when I do `import pymc`, I got the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
      from .CommonDeterministics import *
    File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py", line 21, in <module>
      from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
    File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
      from . import flib
    ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

which can be fixed by manually `import numpy.core.multiarray`, but then, when I try again to `import pymc`, I got another error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
      from .CommonDeterministics import *
    File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py", line 13, in <module>
      from . import PyMCObjects as pm
    ImportError: cannot import name PyMCObjects
```

I googled around, and the solutions to similar problems are either:

1. In case that's related to the installation of `pymc`, force using the 32-bit instead of 64. However, this answer is for Windows users, and I have OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).
2. In other cases, it's usually due to a circular dependency (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194010/python-cannot-import-name-class)), which I don't think is the case here.

My guess is that something is wrong with the package `flib`, but I couldn't figure out what. I would appreciate any answer/hint on this problem. Thanks in advance!

**Update (July-4-2014)**
Thanks, Chris! I rebuilt my `pymc` using the conda build by doing `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/tobeplugged pymc`, and now when I do `import pymc`, a different error message appears:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import CommonDeterministics
  ImportError: cannot import name CommonDeterministics
```

As Chris pointed out (see comments below), the problem(s) is being looked at [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/556). The problem seems to have to do with the version of `gcc` (version 4.9). I will try to rebuild my `gcc` with the older version (4.8.2) later today to see if that will solve the problem for OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). Otherwise, I believe people can wait a little bit for the pymc team to solve this problem, too.

Comment: I just built and uploaded this new package yesterday. When I get a chance, I will see if I can replicate the problem, and get back to you.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I cannot replicate it, but it appears that [others can](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/556).

Comment: Thanks! Please see updates above. Thank you for passing the problem over to the pymc github.