# Module imports and __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I am trying to understand what the best practices are with regards to Python's (v2.7) import mechanics. I have a project that has started to grow a bit and lets say my code is organized as follows:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    Foo.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    module3.py
```

The package name is `foo` and underneath it I have module `Foo.py` which contains code for the class `Foo`. Hence I am using the same name for the package, module and class which might not be very clever to start with.

`__init__.py` is empty and class `Foo` needs to import `module1, module2 and module3` hence part of my `Foo.py` file looks like:

```
# foo/Foo.py

import module1
import module2
import module3

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
....
....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo_obj = Foo()
```

However I later revisited this and I thought it would be better to have all imports in the `__init__.py` file. Hence my `__init__.py` now looks like:

```
# foo/__init__.py

import Foo
import module1
import module2
import module3
....
....
```

and my `Foo.py` only needs to import `foo`:

```
# foo/Foo.py

import foo
```

While this looks convenient since it is a one liner, I am a bit worried that it might be creating circular imports. What I mean is that when the script `Foo.py` is run it will import everything it can and then `__init__.py` will be called which will import `Foo.py` again (is that correct?). Additionally using the same name for package, module and class makes things more confusing.

Does it make sense the way I have done it? Or am I asking for trouble?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

A couple things you could do to improve your organization, if only to adhere to some popular Python conventions and standards.

If you search this topic, you will inevitably run across people recommending the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) guidelines.  These are the *de facto* canonical standards for organizing python code.

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
> used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
> should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
> underscores is discouraged.

Based on these guidelines, your project modules should be named like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    module3.py
```

I find it's generally best to avoid importing modules unnecessarily in `__init__.py` unless you're doing it for namespace reasons.  For example, if you want the namespace for your package to look like this

```
from foo import Foo
```

instead of

```
from foo.foo import Foo
```

Then it makes sense to put

```
from .foo import Foo
```

in your `__init__.py`.  As your package gets larger, some users may not want to use all of the sub-packages and modules, so it doesn't make sense to force the user to wait for all those modules to load by implicitly importing them in your `__init__.py`.  Also, you have to consider whether you even want `module1`, `module2`, and `module3` as part of your external API.  Are they only used by `Foo` and not intended to be for end users?  If they're only used internally, then don't include them in the `__init__.py`

I'd also recommend using [absolute or explicit relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) for importing sub-modules.  For example, in `foo.py`

#### Absolute

```
from foo import module1
from foo import module2
from foo import module3
```

#### Explicit Relative

```
from . import module1
from . import module2
from . import module3
```

This will prevent any possible naming issues with other packages and modules.  It will also make it easier if you decide to support Python3, since the implicit relative import syntax you're currently using is not supported in Python3.

Also, files inside your package generally shouldn't contain a

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

This is because running a file as a script means it won't be considered part of the package that it belongs to, so it won't be able to make relative imports.

The best way to provide executable scripts to users is by using the [`scripts` or `console_scripts` feature of `setuptools`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html).  The way you organize your scripts can be different depending on which method you use, but I generally organize mine like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    ...
scripts/
     foo_script.py
setup.py
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports. It's recommended to use absolute imports. I don't think author's example tends to be "complex structure" there it's okay to use relative imports.

Comment: @TheGodfather  Yes, either way is acceptable.  It's funny, I tend to prefer relative imports in simple projects because I think it's easier to read.  But in complex projects where there are multiple sub-packages and imports across different parts of the hierarchy, I think absolute is much clearer.   Both are better than implicit relative (ie. `import module1`).

Comment: Many thanks, very thorough reply! Helps a lot my understanding

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "This is because running a file as a script means it won't be considered part of the package that it belongs to, so it won't be able to make relative imports."? So if I should remove all scripts follows `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside a module to prevent the relative import(s) be broken?

Answer (score 8):

According to [PEP 0008, "Public and internal interfaces"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces):

> Imported names should always be considered an implementation detail. Other modules must not rely on indirect access to such imported names unless they are an explicitly documented part of the containing module's API, such as os.path or a package's `__init__` module that exposes functionality from submodules.

So this would suggest that it *is* ok to put imports in the `__init__` module, if `__init__` is being used to expose functions from submodules. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200818162939/https://mikegrouchy.com/blog/be-pythonic-__init__py) is a short blog post I found with a couple examples of Pythonic uses of `__init__`, using imports to make subpackages available at package level.

Your example of moving the import statements to `__init__` in order to have only one import in `Foo`, does **not** seem to follow this rule. My interpretation is that the imports in your `__init__` should be used for *external* interfaces, otherwise, just put your import statements in the file that needs them. This saves you trouble when submodule names change and keeps you from unnecessary or difficult-to-find imports when you add more files that use a different subset of submodules.

As far as circular references, this is definitely possible in Python ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)). I wrote about that before I actually tried your toy example, but to make the example work I had to move `Foo.py` up a level, like so:

```
Foo.py
foo/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    module3.py
```

With that setup and some print statements, running `python Foo.py` gives the output:

```
module 1
module 2
module 3
hello Foo constructor
```

and exits normally. Note that this is due to adding the `if __name__ == "__main__"` - if you add a print statement outside of that, you can see Python is still loading the module twice. A better solution would be to remove the import from your `__init__.py`. As I said earlier, that may or may not make sense, depending on what those submodules are.

Comment: Just one comment - in blog post you refer to it's recommended to use constructions like "from mypackage import *". But it's not recommended by PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports, you should avoid wildcards imports

Comment: I didn't interpret the blog post as advocating that construction per se, but just using it to show how `__all__` works (which has its own set of style issues.. but that's another topic). Regardless, you're certainly right in that wildcard imports are not good style!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the 'Style Guide for Python Code' for best practices, the import is kept in the class in that guide.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### package1

> package1.py
>
> __init__.py

### package2

> test.py

### package1.py:-

```
class abc:
    a = 'hello'
    def print_a(self):
    print(a)
```

### __init__.py:-

```
from .package1 import abc
```

### package2.py:-

```
From package1.package1 import abc
```

I use these __init__.py to import from a package.

Answer (score 0):

I can't state definitively if this is the correct way, but I've always done it the former way. That is, I have always kept `__init__.py` empty, and just imported things within `Foo.py` as needed.

From how you describe it, it does seem like there is some circular logic happening in the latter form.