# Setting up imports and __init__.py in a multi-module project

Tags: python

### The problem

I've found dozens of articles and tutorials about the basics of using import in Python, but none that would provide a comprehensive guide on setting up your own Python project with multiple packages.

This is my project's structure:

- `codename/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `package1.py` (has `class1` and is a script)
  - `package2.py` (has `class2`)
  - `package3.py` (has `function1` and is a script)
- `test/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `test_package1.py` (has unit tests for `package1`)
  - `test_package3.py` (has unit tests for `package3`)

How do I setup my imports to have the following requirements met (and do all of them make sense?):

1. `class1`, `class2` and `function1` are in namespace `codename`, i.e. this works:

   ```
   import codename
   obj = codename.class1()
   codename.function1(obj)
   ```
2. they may be imported the same way using `from codename import *` or `from codename import class1`
3. `function1` can easily access `class1` (how?)
4. `package1` and `package2` are executable scripts
5. so are `test_package1.py` and `test_package3.py`
6. tests are also executable via `python -m unittest discover`
7. scripts are also executable via `python -m codename.package1`

For some reasons I'm having issues with having all of these met and when I try to fix one issue, another one pops out.

### What have I tried?

- Leaving `codename/__init__.py` empty satisfies **almost** all of the requirements, because everything works, but leaves names like `class1` in their module's namespaces - whereas I want them imported into the package.
- Adding `from codename.package1 import class1` et al again satisfies most of the requirements, but I get a warning when executing the script via `python -m codename.package1`:

  ```
  RuntimeWarning: 'codename.package2' found in sys.modules \
  after import of package 'codename', but prior to execution of \
  'codename.package2'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  ```

which sort of makes sense...
Running the script via `python codename/package1.py` functions, but I guess I would probably like both ways to work.

- I ran into [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/1794022) that stated that internal modules should not also be scripts, but I don't understand why we get the `-m` switch then? Anyway, extracting the `main`s into an external `scripts` directory works, but is it the only canonical way of setting all of this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you'll need to add the parent directory of `codename/` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (or write/use a `setup.py` file, or modify `sys.path` at runtime)
2. You'll need to import all names that you want to export in `codename/__init__.py`
3. `from .package1 import function1` if you write/use a `setup.py` file, otherwise `from codename.package1 import function1`
4. You should use a `setup.py` file for scripts/executables since it makes everything much cleaner (and you'll need a `setup.py` file sooner or later anyway)
5. (and 6.) I would suggest using `py.test` it will find all tests for you automagically (and can run them in parallel etc.)
6. That should work out-of-the-box, but if you've written a `setup.py` then you can run them from anywhere (and on any platform) as just `package1`.

Comment: 3. this doesn't work. I've added a setup.py file, used both install and develop and I'm getting
`No module named '__main__.package1'; __main__ is not a package` when running the script normally and
`Cannot import name 'package1'` on the `from .package1 import...` line.

But anyway, by looking through setup.py's documentation I guess it's a standard procedure to have the scripts separated from the modules and not use -m: is that true?

Comment: You'll need to use the `entry_points` feature of `setup.py`, e.g. https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps/blob/master/setup.py (the syntax is command_name = importable.dotted.path:function_name).

Comment: Ahh, now it works! Thanks a bunch. I've also found a very useful article on setting up executables in a python project: https://chriswarrick.com/pl/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/

Comment: Nice resource. Thx.