# How to structure object-oriented Python 3 project and its imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a object-oriented Python 3.7 project with a structure along the following lines:

```sh
├── plugins
│   ├── book_management
│   │   ├── book_inserter.py
│   │   ├── book_remover.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── book.py
│   │   ├── book_sampler.py
│   │   ├── operators
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── register_book.py
│   │   │   ├── unregister_book.py
│   │   │   └── mark_book_as_missing.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── reader_management
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── reader.py
│   │   ├── reader_creator.py
│   │   ├── reader_emailer.py
│   │   ├── reader_remover.py
│   │   ├── operators
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── create_reader.py
│   │   │   ├── remove_reader.py
│   │   │   └── email_reader.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── book_management_tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_book.py
│   │   ├── test_book_inserter.py
│   │   ├── test_book_remover.py
│   │   ├── test_book_sampler.py
│   │   ├── test_mark_book_as_missing_operator.py
│   │   ├── test_register_book_operator.py
│   │   ├── test_unregister_book_operator.py
│   ├── reader_management_tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_reader.py
│   │   ├── test_reader_creator.py
```

In a test like `test_mark_book_as_missing_operator` I end up having imports like:

```py
from plugins.book_management.book_inserter import BookInserter
from plugins.book_management.operators.mark_book_as_missing import (
    MarkBookAsMissingOperator
)
from plugins.reader_management.reader_creator import ReaderCreator
from plugins.reader_management.operators.create_reader import (
    CreateReaderOperator
)
```

This feels really bad having these really verbose partial imports. So I am guessing I must be doing it wrong. Ideally, importing `plugins.reader_management` and `plugins.reader_management.operators` possibly as something shorter would seem much more readable.

`book_inserter.py` is defining a single class `BookInserter`. Ideally, I would like to keep this 1-class / 1-file structure. Obvisouly, this leads to an inflation of the number of files but also allows of shorter more focused files. But if this is deeply non-Pythonic I am willing to hear why and how I should adapt the code structure.

Finally I have been using this kind of several layer architectures (`plugins/*_management/operators/*.py`) but this leads to very long import lines, and I am frequently having legitimate lint issues as a result.

I have been considering importing submodules from top modules (like book_management, in `book_management/__init__.py`) but I am not sure if it is good practice and also it seems like a violation of the principle of not having unused imports in your files. (Also would I be at risk of circular imports as a result?)

My main question in short: what would be a(the?) Pythonic way to structure such a project and setup the imports (with ideally some justification of why this would be a/the Pythonic way to do it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727134/module-imports-and-init-py-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is perfectly fine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) to use `__init__.py` to compress your namespace. Use `__all__` to clearly define that imported names are meant for export.

```
# plugins/book_management/__init__.py
from .book_inserter import BookInserter
from .operators.mark_book_as_missing import MarkBookAsMissingOperator
# more imports

__all__ = [
    'BookInserter',
    'MarkBookAsMissingOperator',
    # more exports
]
```

This reduces the length and number of imports on usage:

```
# test_mark_book_as_missing_operator
from plugins.book_management import BookInserter, MarkBookAsMissingOperator
from plugins.reader_management import ReaderCreator, CreateReaderOperator
```

There seems not to be a consensus whether 1-definition-per-file is a *bad* thing. For the standard library and many third-party modules it is customary to keep all directly related classes and functions together, though.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with absolute imports or would that lead to circular imports?

Comment: @sunless Do you mean ``from plugins.book_inserter import BookInserter`` instead? Relative imports have exactly the same behaviour as such absolute imports, they merely avoid repeating and hard-coding the package name.