# Importing classes from different directory within the same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have the next directory structure:

```
.
├── models
│   ├── description.py
│   ├── identification.py
│   └── person.py
└── utils
    └── generators
        └── person.py
```

I'm getting the next error while importing the classes in each file that exist within the `models` directory:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/generators/person.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.person import Person
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

And this is the code in my `utils/generators/person.py` file:

```
from models.person import Person
from models.identification import Identification
from models.description import Description
```

How can I import those classes in my file?

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: From my terminal: `python utils/generators/person.py`

Comment: Did you install the ``models`` module? Did you set ``PYTHONPATH``?

Comment: can you try adding the current folder "." to your PYTHONPATH? e.g. run this from your terminal `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"." python utils/generators/person.py`

Comment: The pythonpath solution ain't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Python does not search for modules on import in the directories that are descendants of the upper-level directories.

To eliminate this problem you can introduce a `main.py` in the root (you marked it as dot) that would do the imports into the common namespace.

On a separate note, as wisely pointed out in the comments, it is no longer necessary to add empty `__init__.py` files ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/6573902)) for Python 3.3+ so this cannot be the issue for Python 3.

Comment: Isn't this a python2 thing? I'm using python3

Comment: While ``__init__.py`` files are recommended, Python3 will treat a folder without one as a namespace package.

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez: if you find the answer useful could you please consider accepting it?

Comment: I just used this one and it doesn't work either. I'm getting the same error!

Comment: It is a pity! I am wondering what your PYTHONPATH looks like.