# How do I import something from a nested child directory with Python?

Tags: python

In my main file (root level), I have:

```
from deepspeech2_utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss
```

And I also have an `__init__.py` that has:

```
from submodules.deepspeech2 import utils as deepspeech2_utils
```

I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
main.py
__init__.py
-submodules
  -deepspeech2
    -utils.py
```

But I get an error:

```
    from deepspeech2_utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss
ImportError: No module named deepspeech2_utils
```

I also tried:

```
from submodules.deepspeech2.utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss
```

but get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `deepspeech2` is in `submodules`

Comment: And if you ad a blank `__init__.py` deepspeech2? If not would try to add init to submodels too

Comment: As you have stated your directory structure `from submodules.deepspeech2.utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss` this code will work

Comment: @Shamoon Which version of Python do you use? [Namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) where introduced in version 3.3, so your code should work without problem: `from submodules.deepspeech2.utils import ...`.

Comment: You get exactly the same message? Maybe you have a typo in `from submodules.deepspeech2.utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way directories are recognized as modules in python is by the presence of an `__init__.py` file within those directories. These `__init__.py` files don't need to have code. So change your directory structure to look like this

```
root
    main.py
    __init__.py
    submodules
        __init__.py
        deepspeech2
            __init__.py
            utils.py
```

Now once this is done, your import statement
(which didn't work without the above directory changes) in `__init__.py` has a scope, it will not be visible within your `main.py` - that has a different scope. In order to achieve what you are doing change your import statement in main.py to

`from root.deepspeech2_utils import reduce_tensor, check_loss`

I have to advise apart from namespacing reasons, importing in `__init__.py` is not encouraged, since users of your module may just want to import specific things from your module/submodules and your import statements in `__init__.py` will force them to have more imports than they want. [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/2277013) from another post that talks about such concerns in detail

Answer (score 0):

You need put inside all subfolders **init**.py for convert this folders on modules and impoprt form this folders.