# How to Call any Function Inside a Custom Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I've created a package called `pack` with a couple of modules, organized like this:

```
pack
 |--pack
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- main.py
    |-- controller.py
 |--setup.py
 |--README.md
```

In `main.py` and `controller.py` I have all the functions that I need from the package. In this case, in order to call `just_a_random_function` inside `controller.py` I would have to do:

```
from pack import controller

controller.just_a_random_function
```

But I need to make this easier, like this:

```
import pack
pack.just_a_random_function
```

I think I'm a little bit lost about how I need to organize my package, what do I need to change in order to, just importing the package, being able to call all the package functions?

Comment: Add to `init` file the following string ` from controller import just_a_random_function `

Comment: This question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: Check out this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1bbbwk/whats_your_opinion_on_what_to_include_in_init_py/

Comment: See this answer, which describes what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/3228591

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in some coments and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/3228591), the solution would be to add this into `__init__.py` file:

```
from pack.controller import just_a_random_function
```

Then, in order to call `just_a_random_function()`, I just need to import `pack`:

```
import pack
pack.just_a_random_function
```