# Why can I only use my package with "from" import?

Tags: python, python-packaging

When installing my package in editable mode (`pip install -e .`), I can only use it's functions using an import with from:

```py
from package import hello_world

hello_world.hello_world()
```

using only import doesn't work:

```py
import package

package.hello_world.hello_world()
```

This results in `NameError: name 'hello_world' is not defined`

Is there something I need to set up in my package, so that I can just import the package?

Comment: you have to use `import package.hello_world` to import code from file `package/hello_world.py`

Comment: if in file `package/__init__.py` you use `from .hello_world import *` then in code you can use `import package` and run directly `package.hello_world()` without middle `.hello_world.`

Comment: in file `package/__init__.py` you have to use `from . import hello_world`

Comment: you could show what you have in `package/__init__.py` and `package/hello_world.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file `package/__init__.py` you have to use `from . import hello_world`

---

At this moment you can only do `import package.hello_world`

Comment: Thanks! I changed this to `from package import hello_world` which also works well :) Thanks to your hint with the `__init__.py` I also found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733111/18904265