# Python multiple files variables and functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to split my python code into a few files :

**`file1.py`**

```
from file2 import *

var1 = 7
func_file2()
```

**`file2.py`**

```
def func_file2():
    var2 = var1
```

So it says:

```
NameError: global name 'var1' is not defined
```

How can I fix that?

I tried to import file1 in file2.

Comment: You should avoid using `*` to import. It clutters your namespace and can cause funny problems when you have two variables with the same names or even variables that have the same name as built-in functions. Just a general tip.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just changed my variables name to make it easier to understand, fixed !

Comment: and please don't do cyclic imports! read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756028/import-module-defined-in-another-module/37756322#37756322

Comment: because in file1.py, you first import everything from fil2.py. You define var1 after the import!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I didn't know about cyclic imports, I will take a look to make a proper code :)

Answer (score 1):

`var1` is defined in `file1` but you are referencing it in `file2`. You could move `var1` to `file2` to fix the error.

**file1.py**

```
from file2 import *    
func_file2()
```

**file2.py**

```
def func_file2():
    var1 = 7
    var2 = var1
```

You might be tempted to import `file1` in `file2` first to define `var1` but that would cause a cyclic import (both `file1` & `file2` would reference each other).

Comment: Is it common to use getters in Python or I should use this way of coding ?

Comment: @SteevenBrunner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 0):

func_file2 doesn't have visibility of your variable var1 because when it's defined the var1 doesn't exist in any scope so the closure doesn't work.

When you write modules in python, follow the principle of cohesion that means that if a function in a module uses a variable from another module something can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you to use global variables however if you want it to work the way it is now, you can do something like this:

```
first file
global var1 
var1 = 7

second file
from first_file_name import var1 #this will make your var1 accessible from the second file
```

I hope it helps.