# How to organize one Blueprint with multiple routes files

Tags: python, flask

I got Blueprint working properly.

App structure:

```
application.py 

users/routes.py
```

In application.py I register the blueprint:

```
app.register_blueprint( users, url_prefix = '/users' )
```

And in users/routes.py I create it:

```
users = Blueprint( 'users', __name__, template_folder = "usersViews" )
@users.route( '/registration', methods = [ 'GET' ] )
def get_register_user_form( ):
    # Code......
```

What I need to do is add other files into users/ from which I need to use @users.route like in:

```
users/route2.py

users/route3.py
```

But this won't work as the blueprint is only created in the original users/routes.py. I'm not sure the proper way to handle this case ? I guess recreating the blueprint in each route file with users = Blueprint( 'users', **name**, template_folder = "usersViews" ) is not the proper way to do so. So how could I achieve that ?

Comment: in route2.py, how about `from routes import users` ?

Comment: hmmm where do you get "routes" from ?

Comment: It's the name of your first file, where you create the blueprint.

Comment: indeed this is common sense and should work but browser gets a 404 Not Found

Comment: ah, perhaps `from users.routes` then, if it's all being called from the root directory of the application

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would split some of this out into `__init__.py` files like this:

app structure:

```
__init__.py (main app)
users/__init__.py (for blueprint)
users/routes.py
users/routes2.py
users/routes3.py
```

then, in the main `__init__.py` setup your blueprints:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

from .users import users as user_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint, url_prefix='/users')

return app
```

now, in your `users/__init__.py` something like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, url_for

users = Blueprint('users', __name__)

from . import routes, routes2, routes3
```

Then in `users/routes.py`, `users/routes2.py`, etc:

```
from . import users
```

Caveat: I've never actually done this! But this is the pattern I use for Flask blueprints and it seemed like it would solve your problem.

Comment: Genius, this is working, the secret was in the init files !!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks! Why does from . import routes, routes2, routes3 needs to be after users = .... in users/__init__.py ?

Comment: This is to avoid circular dependencies because the "routes" files also need to import the users Blueprint. It is essentially an "order of operations" thing with regards to how the code is read, some good discussion on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing

Comment: found it really helpful. the order of imports was the key