# Kivy, ImportError: cannot import name App

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

everything was working fine on my ubuntu machine and suddenly i can't import `App` from `kivy.app`

```
from kivy.app import App
```

[image]

Comment: What is `/home/samar/new.py`? Can you remove or rename it?

Comment: @kennytm python file with a single line code `from kivy.app import App`

Comment: Yes. Does it work if you rename it to e.g. `test_new.py`?

Comment: yeah. how? why? what was that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

One of Kivy's internal module `weakmethod.py` is trying to import another internal module `new.py`. But you have create a `new.py` next to where you run python, so Python will try to load yours first. This breaks everything because `weakmethod` doesn't expect that your `new.py`, it wants the internal `new.py`!. The solution is to rename this offending file.

(The actual problem causing ImportError is [circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing) on the `kivy.app` module)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the import error "cannot import name app" was syntax. I replaced app with App and that solved my problem. I was able to re-create, and resolve the issue, by changing the case from lower to upper and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure:

1. Go to kivy website
2. Go to -> download -> Windows 7, 8, 10 (32/64 bit) Install using pip, follow the instructions **here** -> installation for Windows
3. Copy and pasted in CMD->`python -m pip install kivy_examples` --> (The examples are installed in the share directory under the root directory where python is installed)
4. For example `C:\Python34\share\kivy-examples\animation`
5. Save all your files in this folder.

Comment: I feel like you could format this answer in a better way, and explain what you are doing on each step.