# Having trouble with imports in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I use Python 2.7. I'm trying to run my UI-automation script, but I got ImportError.

I have at least 30 Classes with methods. I want to have these methods in each and any class that's why I created BaseClass(MainClass) and created objects of all my classes. Please advise what should I do in this case or how I can solve this problem.

Here the example what similar to my code.

test_class/baseclass.py

```
from test_class.first_class import FirstClass
from test_class.second_class import SecondClass


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstclass = FirstClass()
        self.secondclass = SecondClass()
```

test_class/first_class.py

```
from test_class.baseclass import MainClass

class FirstClass(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        MainClass.__init__(self)

    def add_two_number(self):
        return 2 + 2
```

test_class/second_class.py

```
from test_class.baseclass import MainClass

class SecondClass(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        MainClass.__init__(self)

    def minus_number(self):
        return self.firstclass.add_two_number() - 10


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(SecondClass().minus_number())
```

When I run the last file I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nik-edcast/git/ui-automation/test_class/second_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_class.baseclass import MainClass
  File "/Users/nik-edcast/git/ui-automation/test_class/baseclass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_class.first_class import FirstClass
  File "/Users/nik-edcast/git/ui-automation/test_class/first_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_class.baseclass import MainClass
ImportError: cannot import name MainClass
```

Comment: This seems caused by circular import, this may be a dupe of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)

Answer (score 1):

check this line: from test_class.baseclass import MainClass -> it seems like all other imports had a '_' between the names like second_class. So try maybe to write base_class. who knows might work

Answer (score 0):

Are you proabably running your code like `python test_class/second_class.py`. If you just do this then python will think the base directory to find modules is `./test_class`. So when you import the `test_class` package python will start looking for a folder called `./test_class/test_class` to find the sub-modules. This directory doesn't exist and so the import fails. There are several ways that you can tell python how to correctly find your modules.

### Using `PYTHONPATH`

One way to get around this is to set `PYTHONPATH` before starting python. This is just an environment variable with which you can tell python where to look for your modules.

eg.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/root/folder
python test_class/second_class.py
```

### Using the `-m` switch for python

Be default python treats the directory of the main module as the place to look for other modules. However, if you use `-m` python will fall back to looking in the current directory. But you also need to specify the full name of the module you want to run (rather than as a file). eg.

```
python -m test_class.second_class
```

### Writing a root entry point

In this we just define your main module at the base level (the directory that contains `test_class`. Python will treat this folder as the place to look for user modules and will find everything appropriately. eg.

#### main.py (in `/path/to/your/root/folder`)

```
from test_class.second_class import SecondClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(SecondClass().minus_number())
```

#### at the command line

```
python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try importing the full files instead of using from file import class. Then you would only need to add the file name before referencing something from another file.