# importing from folder in same package in python

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid

i am using pyramid in views.py

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
import os
import uuid
import shutil
import hashlib
from .service.fun import *

def forservo():
    return "HAppy HERE"


@view_config(route_name='home',request_method='GET')
def home(request):
    return Response('html')
```

in fun.py

```
from ..views import *

print forservo()
```

it throws error saying name 'forservo' is not defined

folder structure is

```
myapp
  myapp
  service
    __init__.py
    fun.py
  __init__.py
  views.py
```

Comment: Your main folder tree ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus added folder tree in que

Comment: You are trying to do a circular import. views.py can import from fun.py OR fun.py can import from views, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @StevePiercy but i need both files to import from each other is there no way?

Comment: You can use a circular import, but IMO you should not. Instead see answer by @Sergey or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [cyclic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) - `fun.py` imports from `views.py` and `views.py` imports from `fun.py`.

In this situation, things happen roughly like this:

- Python opens `views.py` and executes it up to the line `from .service.fun import *`
- It then has to stop executing `views.py` and opens `fun.py`.
- The very first line of `fun.py` tells it to stop and import `views.py`
- The import statement returns the partially-executed module which does not yet have `forservo` function defined.

Cyclic imports can be resolved by moving the common bits of code needed both by fun.py  and views.py into a separate module. A less elegant solution is to move some imports below the functions which are causing the cyclic import error or make them local inside a function which needs the import.

Answer (score 0):

In this folder structure

```
myapp
  myapp 
   service
   __init__.py
   fun.py
  __init__.py
  views.py
```

Where views.py has the content

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
import os
import uuid
import shutil
import hashlib
from .service.fun import *

def forservo():
    return "HAppy HERE"


@view_config(route_name='home',request_method='GET')
def home(request):
    return Response('html')
```

Then import statement in fun.py is:

```
from myapp.views import forservo()

print forservo()
```

and this will print "HAppy HERE"

Comment: i added folder structure and it is quite opposite

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name forservo