# ABC Chlid Class Issue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my Django App I have a module dropdown

```
dropdown
  __init_.py
  select.py
  inline.py
```

In select.py have a class

```
from inline import doauto
class AbstractOption(ABC):
  def method1:
  def method2:
class Select(AbstractOption):
  def load_request:
  def method_helper:
    ....
     doauto()
    ....
```

In inline.py i have a class

```
class Inlineselect(AbstractOption):
   def load_request:
   def method_helper:

def doauto:
 inl= Inlineselect()
 inl.load_request()
```

> I am getting following error: ImportError: cannot import name
>   AbstractOption from select (/../../select.py)

I am not getting why this issue is coming. in inline.py i imported AbstractOption class from select.py and when I am using a child class from inline in select module class it gives class import error.

Comment: You are doing `from select.py import AbstractOption`, right? I guess it's an issue of circular imports. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing) question and others related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: select is a built-in module. You should probably name your module something else... (or learn about relative vs. absolute imports).

Comment: @thebjorn my filename is different.

Comment: You need to provide sample code that displays your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is called circular import problem. Whenever you import something from other modules or packages, that something needs to be defined, before that can be imported. Below code should solve the problem.

## select.py

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractOption(ABC):
    def method1:
        pass

    def method2:
        pass

from inline import doauto

class Select(AbstractOption):
    def load_request:
        pass

    def method_helper:
        doauto()
```

## inline.py

```
from select import AbstractOption

class Inlineselect(AbstractOption):
    def load_request:
        pass

    def method_helper:
        pass

def doauto:
    inl = Inlineselect()
    inl.load_request()
```