# Python Flask - Error Handling with blueprints

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am using flask and I have my packages by feature and am using blue prints and this works nicely but I would like to have a global 404 and error page which sits outside of any specific feature package.

When I trigger a 404 flask handles this with the default 404 handler still and I dont get my custom template. Below is my code:

**init**.py

```
# Define the WSGI application object
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load Configuration
app.config.from_object('config')

from .user.route import mod_user as user_module
from .route.error_handler import mod_error as error_module

# Register blueprints
app.register_blueprint(user_module)
app.register_blueprint(error_module)
```

error_handler.py

```
import traceback

from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint

mod_error = Blueprint('error', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@mod_error.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    print(e)
    return render_template('404.html')


@mod_error.errorhandler(Exception)
def general_error(e):
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    return render_template('error.html')
```

My feature routes are defined in `project.user.route.py`

Global route\error handler is in `project.route.error_handler.py`

Global error templates are in `project.templates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work this out and it is pretty simple, when I moved from everything in one script to using blueprints and I created the error handling module I thought I needed to use the module name in my annotation:

`@mod_error.errorhandler(404)`

The reason for this is because this is how I did it in my controller for my user feature:

`@mod_user.route('/read', methods=['POST', 'GET'])`

Below is what I needed to do, which is import my app object and then use this for the error handler functions:

```
import traceback

from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint
from .. import app

mod_error = Blueprint('error', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    print(e)
    return render_template('404.html')


@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def general_exception(e):
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    return render_template('error.html')
```

This now handles all errors at a global level outside of any of my feature packages, I wanted to achieve the effect of a `ControllerAdvice` that handles all exceptions for all controllers in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to import the `app` object like @berimbolo said. Yes, he does have the right idea, because in flask, for the 404 and other routing errors, the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/#handling:) say:

> the blueprint cannot handle 404 routing errors because the 404 occurs at the routing level before the blueprint can be determined.

So, you can't handle a 404 error using the `errorhandler()` on a blueprint. This won't work for 404 errors:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint
mod_error = Blueprint('error', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@mod_error.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    ...
```

Instead, you must add the error handler onto the application object, like @berimbolo did:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    print(e)
    return render_template('404.html')
```

But, **the problem with this** is you're increasing the change you'll hit a circular import issue ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing) sort of issue). Because the module where the `app` object is declared will likely import the module where the `blueprint` object is declared, at the same time as the `blueprint` module then imports the `app` module to get at the `app` object.

**The solution**: is to use the `app_errorhandler` [method on the blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=app_errorhandler#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler) object. It's docstring says:

> Like :meth:`Flask.errorhandler` but for a blueprint.  This      handler is used for all requests, even if outside of the blueprint.

This means you don't have to do the circular import thing. Instead, you can write:

```
import traceback
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint

mod_error = Blueprint('error', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@mod_error.app_errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    print(e)
    return render_template('404.html')

@app.app_errorhandler(Exception)
def general_exception(e):
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    return render_template('error.html')
```