# ImportError: cannot import name 'GuideTeacher' from 'teacher.models'

Tags: python, django, django-models, importerror

I have a Teacher model and a Academic model. When i import something in academic model from teacher model Then I found a Import Error like

> File "/media/sajib/Work/Project/schoolmanagement/teacher/models.py", line 3, in 
>       from academic.models import Department, ClassInfo, Section, Session, Shift
>     File "/media/sajib/Work/Project/schoolmanagement/academic/models.py", line 2, in 
>       from teacher.models import GuideTeacher
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'GuideTeacher' from 'teacher.models' (/media/sajib/Work/Project/schoolmanagement/teacher/models.py)

Now how can i solve this?
academic/models.py

```
from teacher.models import GuideTeacher
class ClassRegistration(models.Model):
    department_select = (
        ('general', 'General'),
        ('science', 'Science'),
        ('business', 'Business'),
        ('humanities', 'Humanities')
    )
    department = models.CharField(choices=department_select, max_length=15, null=True)
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(ClassInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    guide_teacher = models.OneToOneField(GuideTeacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['class_name', 'section', 'shift', 'guide_teacher']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.class_name)
```

teacher/models.py

```
from academic.models import Department, ClassInfo, Section, Session, Shift
class GuideTeacher(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(PersonalInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [**Circular Import**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing). To get rid of the situation, remove the import statement in `academic/models.py` and specify **FK related model using string representation**

```
guide_teacher = models.OneToOneField('teacher.GuideTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Have you removed the line `from teacher.models import GuideTeacher` from `academic/models.py` file?

Comment: use `'teacher.GuideTeacher'` (which is a ***string*** -- use single quotes or double quotes)

Comment: You can remove the "probably" from the answer.