# How to import child module which imports parent module?

Tags: python, python-module

I have my module structure as following:

```
/parent
-- __init__.py
-- /child
---- __init__.py
```

I want to import `child` in `parent` and vice versa, I.E.:

/parent/**init**.py:

```
import child
```

/parent/child/**init**.py:

```
import parent
```

but when I do it I get the error `No module named 'parent' in parent/child/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because of the circular dependency of modules in your code.

When python tries to initialize your `parent` module it sees the `import child` statement, which leads the interpreter to the `child` module, (Notice that `parent` module is not initialized yet) now in the child module `import parent` line is encountered, but since the parent module is not initialized yet, the interpreter will fail with the error that it cannot find the `parent` module.

Ideally, you should fix the circular imports to solve this problem, But it can be overcome moving the import to a later stage instead of adding it at the top of the file. (For example: you can add the import statement in a method where you will be actually using the child module.) but it is not recommended to do this.

Comment: How does one "fix circular imports"?

Comment: You will have to rearrange your code so that your parent module does not depend on the child.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parent path before importing it in child, this way parent module can be found

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Comment: This solution only works if you are writing your code directly from `parent`, but what if there is another "grandparent" module which imports `parent`? then the appended path breaks (i.e. `abspath('..')` returns the path to "grandparent" instead of `parent`)

Comment: @Tomergt45 a grandparent module can directly import parent if you put a `__init__.py` file

Comment: I added `print(os.path.abspath('..'))` in `child` and executed them one by one where each imports their child (grandparent imports parent, parent imports child), `child` printed `grandparent/parent`, `parent` printed `grandparent` and `grandparent` printed the path to it's parent directory

Comment: so the imports should work now, or is there something I don't understand ?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is bad, When I import `parent` in `grandparent`, it imports `child` in `parent`, in `child` it appends `abspath(..)` to look for its parent, but because the code runs from `grandparent` then `abspath(..)` returns the parent directory of `grandparent` and not `child`, which means `child` can't import `parent`

Comment: what if in child you do the import with `import grandparent.parent` ? I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it

Comment: it's the same problem because `child` doesn't know where to find `grandparent`

Answer (score 0):

## Bad design alert

**Circular imports problems can indicate bad design**

## Solution

Your imports can't be both on top level.

```py
# /parent/child/init.py:

import parent  # <-- top level

# /parent/init.py:

import .child  # <-- also top level
```

Common pattern is to move one of the import to place, where it is used (but not on top level), eg:

```py
# /parent/child/init.py:

def dupa():
    import parent  # <-- not top level
    parent.foo()
```

## See also

[Python circular importing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, in reality, my parent module is `utils` and my child module is `tfutils` which indicates utils for `tensorflow`, I need some of the functions in `utils` inside `tfutils` so that's the reason for my circular imports