# How can I create access between two or more files

Tags: python, import

I want the main.py to have access to file.py and vise versa

```
>main.py
>folder
   |-->file.py
```

for example, I have 2 classes located in two files:

in main.py

```
class MyClass():
   #somecode
```

in file.py

```
class Tools1():
   #somecode
```

I have tried to use import at the start of each file but then I got an ImportError

main.py

```
from folder.file import Tools1
```

file.py

```
from main import MyClass
```

then I got this error when I run the main.py

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Tools1' from partially initialized module 'folder.file' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

**Is what I am doing posible in python? If so what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing

Answer (score 0):

you should not import main from folder.file, because of recursion problem:

1. `main` will try to import `folder.file.Tools1`, which is a part of `foler.file`
2. `folder.file` has an import of `main.MyClass` at the top, which is a part of `main`
3. then, `folder.file` will try to import `main`
4. `main` has an import of `folder.file.Tools1` at the top

Then it follows to step 1, and it will roll around recursively.

Better to write code without complex collisions, just import your `Tools1` from `main` and operate with them right in `main`. If you want import both of them, you can add create one more file and import both of them in that file.